# Is changing your name multiple times in Geometry Dash possible?

Tags: geometry-dash

I accidentally changed my brother's account name and can't change it back. Is it possible to change it again?

Answer (score 3):

I do not personally play Geometry Dash, but [as per the Geometry Dash forums](http://gdforum.freeforums.net/thread/6212/account-name), you can change your account name once every month, which another user also confirmed to be possible [here](http://gdforum.freeforums.net/thread/8228/change-username-more) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/geometrydash/comments/3i1g74/is_there_a_way_to_change_name_twice/).